# Javascript not verifying whether or not special characters are inputted

Tags: javascript, forms

When writing for special characters in password, it does not pass through, only the empty field and 6 character limit are egistered. I checked a bunch of places but I still get no result no matter where I look. When the regex was not there the confirm password entries worked as well, so something is out of place

Javascript:

```
function VerifyAndConfirmPassword() 
{  
    var pw = document.forms["form"]["passPass"].value;
    var pwC = document.forms["form"]["passCPass"].value;

    if(pw == "") 
    {  
       alert("Password field is required");  
       return false;  
    }
   
    if(pw.length < 6) 
    {  
       alert("Password length must be atleast 6 characters");  
       return false
    }

    var validPass = /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]$/

    if(!pw.value.match(validPass))
    {
        alert("Password requires at least one capital and lowercase letter , one number, and one special character")
        return false;
    }

    if(pwC == "") 
    {  
        alert("Confirm Password field is required");  
        return false;  
    }

    if(pw != pwC)
    {
      alert("Passwords do not match");
      return false;
    }

    else
    {
    return true;
    }
} 



function VerifyAndConfirmPassword() 
{  
    var pw = document.forms["form"]["passPass"].value;
    var pwC = document.forms["form"]["passCPass"].value;

    if(pw == "") 
    {  
       alert("Password field is required");  
       return false;  
    }
   
    if(pw.length < 6) 
    {  
       alert("Password length must be atleast 6 characters");  
       return false
    }

    var validPass = /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]$/

    if(!pw.value.match(validPass))
    {
        alert("Password requires at least one capital and lowercase letter , one number, and one special character")
        return false;
    }

    if(pwC == "") 
    {  
        alert("Confirm Password field is required");  
        return false;  
    }

    if(pw != pwC)
    {
      alert("Passwords do not match");
      return false;
    }

    else
    {
    return true;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Assignment4.css">    
    </head>
    <body>
    <form name="form" onsubmit="return FirstName() && LastName() && Address() && City() && PostalCode() && ProvinceValues() && Age() && VerifyAndConfirmPassword()  && Email()" method="post" action="mailto:jjohn@JJohnsonRE.ca">

    <label for="fname">First Name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="txtFirst" maxlength="100" placeholder="Your First Name"><br><br>

    <label for="lname">Last Name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="txtLast"maxlength="100" placeholder="Your Last Name"><br><br>

    <label for="address">Address:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="txtAdd" maxlength="100" placeholder="Address"><br><br>

    <label for="city">City:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="txtCity" maxlength="100" placeholder="City"><br><br>
    
    <label for="postalCode">Postal Code:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="txtPC" maxlength="100" placeholder="Postal Code"><br><br>
    
    <label for="province">Province: (Must use initials)</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="txtPro" maxlength="100" placeholder="Province"><br><br>

    <label for="age">Age:</label><br>
    <input type="number" name="numAge" maxlength="100" placeholder="Age"><br><br>

    <label for="password">Password:</label><br>
    <input type="password" name="passPass" id="passPass" maxlength="100" placeholder="Password"><br><br>

    <span id="message"></span>


    <label for="Cpassword">Confirm Password:</label><br>
    <input type="password" id="passCPass" name="passCPass" maxlength="100" placeholder="Password"><br><br>
    
    <span id="messageC"></span>
    <span id="confirm"></span>


    <label>Your Email:</label><br>
    <input name="txtEmail" type="text" maxlength="100" placeholder="Email"><br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Register Now">
    <input type="reset" value="Clear Form">

        </form>

    <script src="Assignment4.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: added the HTML.

Comment: `if(!pw.value.match(validPass))` - I think `pw.value` should be just `pw`. Your code is probably resulting in a console error. (`pw` already holds the value of the input)

Comment: Thank you, it helped. Now tho all it does is say its invalid even when its all entered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
!pw.value.match(validPass)
```

`pw` is already the value of the input field (defined as `document.forms["form"]["passPass"].value`). Getting the `value` property of a String returns `null`, and thus you get the error. Just use simply:

```js
!pw.match(validPass)
```

You should also be returning the result of `VerifyAndConfirmPassword()` on submit, not `FirstName() && LastName() && Address() && City() && PostalCode() && ProvinceValues() && Age() && VerifyAndConfirmPassword()  && Email()`.

Use:

```js
function VerifyAndConfirmPassword() {
  var pw = document.forms["form"]["passPass"].value;
  var pwC = document.forms["form"]["passCPass"].value;

  if (pw == "") {
    alert("Password field is required");
    return false;
  }

  if (pw.length < 6) {
    alert("Password length must be atleast 6 characters");
    return false
  }

  var validPass = /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]$/

  if (!pw.match(validPass)) {
    alert("Password requires at least one capital and lowercase letter , one number, and one special character")
    return false;
  }

  if (pwC == "") {
    alert("Confirm Password field is required");
    return false;
  }

  if (pw != pwC) {
    alert("Passwords do not match");
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Assignment4.css">
</head>

<body>
  <form name="form" onsubmit="return VerifyAndConfirmPassword()" method="post" action="mailto:jjohn@JJohnsonRE.ca">

    <label for="fname">First Name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="txtFirst" maxlength="100" placeholder="Your First Name"><br><br>

    <label for="lname">Last Name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="txtLast" maxlength="100" placeholder="Your Last Name"><br><br>

    <label for="address">Address:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="txtAdd" maxlength="100" placeholder="Address"><br><br>

    <label for="city">City:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="txtCity" maxlength="100" placeholder="City"><br><br>

    <label for="postalCode">Postal Code:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="txtPC" maxlength="100" placeholder="Postal Code"><br><br>

    <label for="province">Province: (Must use initials)</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="txtPro" maxlength="100" placeholder="Province"><br><br>

    <label for="age">Age:</label><br>
    <input type="number" name="numAge" maxlength="100" placeholder="Age"><br><br>

    <label for="password">Password:</label><br>
    <input type="password" name="passPass" id="passPass" maxlength="100" placeholder="Password"><br><br>

    <span id="message"></span>


    <label for="Cpassword">Confirm Password:</label><br>
    <input type="password" id="passCPass" name="passCPass" maxlength="100" placeholder="Password"><br><br>

    <span id="messageC"></span>
    <span id="confirm"></span>


    <label>Your Email:</label><br>
    <input name="txtEmail" type="text" maxlength="100" placeholder="Email"><br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Register Now">
    <input type="reset" value="Clear Form">

  </form>

  <script src="Assignment4.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Its part of a bigger amount of code. More than just VerifyAndConfirmPassword()

Comment: @Laser_ OK. I removed it for the snippet to work. Feel free to add it back.